# Summation of partial products

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Q: Calculate

> $$S=1+{3\over4}+{3\times5\over4\times8}+{3\times5\times7\over4\times8\times12}+\dots$$

I calculated that the $n$th term is given by $$
\begin{align}
A_n&={3\times5\times7\times\dots\times(2n+1)\over4\times8\times12\times\dots\times4n}\\
&={{(2n+1)!\over2\times4\times8\dots\times2n}\over4^nn!}\\
&={(2n+1)!\over8^n(n!)^2}
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(2n+1)!\over8^n(n!)^2}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1){1\over8^n}}$$

I'm not sure how to proceed

I feel like generating function for $\sum{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}$ would be helpful but don't know how to derieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$A_n={3\times5\times7\times\dots\times(2n+1)\over4\times8\times12\times\dots\times4n}=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{n! 4^n}
=\frac{(-1/2)^n}{n!}\left(-\frac32\right)\ldots\left(-\frac{2n+1}2\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the binomial series for
$$(1+x)^{-3/2}$$
evaluated at $x=-1/2$.

Comment: Yeah the answer's $\sqrt8$ but how to reach the conclusion without already knowing it? If I knew $(1+x)^{(-3/2)}$ was an option i would just expand